# A ganttbar in two parts on the same line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

I want to design a work-package composed of two successive phases. So on the same line I would draw two rectangles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{pgfgantt} 
      
\begin{document}
   
\begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate-yearmonth, 
    vgrid={dotted,draw=none,draw=none}, 
    x unit=0.22cm,  
    y unit chart = 0.6cm, bar height=0.6,
    y unit title = 0.5cm, title height=1,
    time slot unit=month
    ]{2024-09}{2029-09}  %project duration

    \gantttitlecalendar[title/.style={fill=black!30,draw=black}]{year} \\

    \ganttbar{WP0}{2024-09}{2029-09} \\
  \end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `pgfgantt` the bars are by default printed on the same line, unless you end the line with `\\`. So:

```
% the following bars are on the same line:
\ganttbar{label}{from}{to}
\ganttbar{label}{from}{to}
```

versus:

```
% the following bars are on different lines:
\ganttbar{label}{from}{to}\\
\ganttbar{label}{from}{to}
```

To make the chart a bit more clear you can inline the labels:

```
\ganttbar[inline]{WP0a}{2024-09}{2027-05}
\ganttbar[inline]{WP0b}{2027-06}{2029-09}\\
```

To also have a label outside of the chart you can add a dummy bar of any length, for example the full length, just for printing the label:

```
\ganttbar{WP0}{2024-09}{2029-09}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt} 
      
\begin{document}
   
\begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate-yearmonth, 
    vgrid={dotted,draw=none,draw=none}, 
    x unit=0.22cm,  
    y unit chart = 0.6cm, bar height=0.6,
    y unit title = 0.5cm, title height=1,
    time slot unit=month
    ]{2024-09}{2029-09}  %project duration

    \gantttitlecalendar[title/.style={fill=black!30,draw=black}]{year} \\

    \ganttbar{WP0}{2024-09}{2029-09}
    \ganttbar[inline]{WP0a}{2024-09}{2027-05}
    \ganttbar[inline]{WP0b}{2027-06}{2029-09}\\
    \ganttbar{WP1}{2026-01}{2027-01}
  \end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]